Using react-email components produces empty table cell when map over a query inside the react-email component
I am building a responses email to a client. Everything works fine except this code produces empty table cell:
  <Section>
    {tracksInOrder.map((track) => (
      <Row key={track.id}>
        <Column>
          <img src={track.imagePath} alt={track.name} width={50} height={50} className='object-contain rounded' />
        </Column>
        <Column className='flex flex-col w-full justify-center text-base text-ellipsis text-start'>{track.name}</Column>
        <Column className='justify-self-end'>{formatCurrency(track.priceInCents / 100)}</Column>
      </Row>
    ))}
  </Section>

Any idea why?
